# dynamically add ui-sref to an element

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have the following directive

```
.directive('famAction', function () {

        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {action: '='},
            link: link
        };

        function link(scope, element) {
            if (scope.action.hasOwnProperty('state')) {
                element.attr('ui-sref', scope.action.state);
            }
            if (scope.action.hasOwnProperty('func')) {
                element.bind('click', scope.action.func);
            }
        }

        return directive;
    })
```

The problem is that, when adding the `ui-sref` attribute, the attribute isn't *compiled* ant therefore I don't have the generater `href` tag, so the link doesn't work.

How can I do to dynamically add a `ui-sref` attribute to an element and then compile it ?

I even tried this, without success:

```
 .directive('famAction', function () {

        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {action: '='},
            compile: compile
        };

        function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                    if (scope.action.hasOwnProperty('state')) {
                        element.attr('ui-sref', scope.action.state);
                    }
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                    if (scope.action.hasOwnProperty('func')) {
                        element.bind('click', scope.action.func);
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        return directive;
    })
```

PS: My *action* object can be one of the following:

```
{state: 'app.flaws.relevant', icon: 'chain-broken'}
{func: vm.ignoreFlaw, icon: 'ambulance'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add directives to the element currently being compiled! The reason is that Angular has *already* parsed it and extracted the directives to be compiled. In contrast, if you wanted to add an attribute directive to an internal element, you should do it **in the `compile` function** (not in `preLink` - the template has already been compiled there and the addition of the attribute would have no effect). For cases like this, where you want access to the scope, it will not work: `compile` cannot access the scope (it has not been created yet).

What can you do in your case?

1. Manual compilation:

   1. Remove the element that has the `ui-sref` from the template of your `famAction` directive.
   2. In `pre-` or `postLink`, use `$compile` to compile the template of the element that contains the `ui-sref`, i.e. something along the lines of:

      ```
      var uiSrefElem = $compile(
        '<button ui.sref="' + scope.action.state + '">Go!</button>'
      );
      ```
   3. Add this `uiSrefElem` to the element of the directive.
2. Programmatic navigation: Place a function in the scope/controller that uses `$state.go(scope.action.state)`. Call this function when the directive element is clicked.

I would go for (2).

Comment: What I need to do it's pass to my action buttons either a function or a link, you would go for a function that navigate with `$state.go` instead ?

Comment: Yes, I would choose the click handler function that decides itself whether to call another function or navigate with `$state.go`.

Comment: I'll go that way, and btw that's what I've done while waiting for a better answer, I guess I wasn't so sure that it was *angularish* enough, thanks